# Count one field based on another

Tags: python, mongodb

I am a beginner at MongoDB. I have a collection of few million documents. Example of documents:

[image: Example of documents]

I want to find the user_followers_count, user_friends_count and total user_mentions of each unique user_id.

```
data.aggregate([
       {"$group" : {"_id":{"followers_count":"$user_followers_count", "friends_count": "$user_friends_count"}, "followers_count":{"$sum:1"}}} ])
```

I am trying this but couldn't get the result. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can give you the expected output:

```
db.data.aggregate([ {$project:{usr_mentions:{ $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$user_mentions" }, then: { $size: "$user_mentions" }, else: 0} } , user_id:1,user_followers_count:1,user_friends_count:1   }}   ,  {$group:{ _id:"$user_id" , user_followers_total_count:{$sum:"$user_followers_count"} , user_friends_total_count:{$sum:"$user_friends_count"} , usr_mentions_total_count:{ $sum:"$usr_mentions" }     }}    ])
```

the output will look as follow:

```
{ "_id" : userX, "user_followers_total_count" : 50, "user_friends_total_count" : 20, "usr_mentions_total_count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : userY, "user_followers_total_count" : 150, "user_friends_total_count" : 60, "usr_mentions_total_count" : 6 }
```

keep in mind without the mentions count in project stage , the query will need only group stage and will be faster ...

mongod/mongos 4.4 tested:

```
mongos> db.data.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff4f4e6df14d22947f36205"), "tweet_id" : 1, 
"user_id" : 2, "user_followers_count" : 50, "user_friends_count" : 20, 
"user_tweets_count" : 30, "user_mentions" : [ 0, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff4f4f4df14d22947f36206"), "tweet_id" : 3, 
"user_id" : 4, "user_followers_count" : 50, "user_friends_count" : 20, 
"user_tweets_count" : 30, "user_mentions" : [ 0, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff4f58bdf14d22947f36207"), "tweet_id" : 3, 
"user_id" : 4, "user_followers_count" : 50, "user_friends_count" : 20, 
"user_tweets_count" : 30, "user_mentions" : [ 0, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ff4f590df14d22947f36208"), "tweet_id" : 3, 
"user_id" : 4, "user_followers_count" : 50, "user_friends_count" : 20, 
"user_tweets_count" : 30, "user_mentions" : [ 0, 1 ] }

mongos> db.data.aggregate([ {$project:{usr_mentions:{ $cond: { if: { 
$isArray: "$user_mentions" }, then: { $size: "$user_mentions" }, else: 
 0} } , user_id:1,user_followers_count:1,user_friends_count:1   }}   ,  
{$group:{ _id:"$user_id" , user_followers_total_count: 
{$sum:"$user_followers_count"} , user_friends_total_count: 
{$sum:"$user_friends_count"} , usr_mentions_total_count:{ 
$sum:"$usr_mentions" }     }}    ])

{ "_id" : 4, "user_followers_total_count" : 150, 
"user_friends_total_count" : 60, "usr_mentions_total_count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 2, "user_followers_total_count" : 50, 
"user_friends_total_count" : 20, "usr_mentions_total_count" : 2 }
mongos>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is giving me an invalid syntax error.

Comment: ( tested with version 4.4 )

Comment: Apologies. I did some mistake in Pymongo syntax. It worked. Thanks a lot!